# How to parse an xml and get the content of specific element

Tags: java, xpath, xml-parsing

My xml String is

```
Got message from Queue ==> <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003
/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><ns1:PostPublicationResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.openoandm.org/xml/ISBM/"><ns1:Messag
eID>urn:uuid:7d361fb0-bc54-48bd-bbd1-6e34960ef3f8</ns1:MessageID><ns1:MessageContent><MessageContent xmlns="http://www.o
penoandm.org/xml/ISBM/"><hi>k786</hi></MessageContent></ns1:MessageContent></ns1:PostPublicationResponse></soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now i have writtent a function that is trying to get ***Content of element MessageContent i.e `<hi>k786</hi>`*** but i am getting null value always.
My function to parse above xml is:

```
private String parseQueueMessage(String message)
        throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException,
        XPathExpressionException {
    String resultMsg = "";
    DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
            .newInstance();
    domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);

    DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new java.io.StringReader(
            message)));

    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    // XPath Query for showing all nodes value

    xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        @Override
        public Iterator getPrefixes(String arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String getPrefix(String arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String getNamespaceURI(String arg0) {
            if("xmlns:ns1".equals(arg0)) {
                return "http://www.openoandm.org/xml/ISBM/";
            }
            return null;
        }
    });


    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//xmlns:ns1:MessageContent");

    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println("The message obtained after parsing : "
                + nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
        resultMsg = nodes.item(i).getNodeValue();
    }

    return resultMsg;
}
```

What i have done wrong in here?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the name space URI first before selecting from XPATH. For example, first define the namespace URI as follows on the root;

```
element.setAttribute("xmlns:ns1", "http://www.openoandm.org/xml/ISBM/");
xpath.compile("//ns1:MessageContent");
```

Comment: I have changed my code above and implemented the namespace but still it is giving me null when i call nodes.item(i).getNodeValue();

Comment: you do not need the xmlns part on the xpath expression. just use the ns1 attribute

Comment: one more query i have. Suppose i want to extract ns1:MessageID as well ns1:MessageContent. then how should i write my code so that i can get both values saperately at the same time?

Comment: can you try as xpath.compile("//ns1:MessageID|//ns1:MessageContent");

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28487/discussion-between-roy-and-dinukadev)

Answer (score 0):

//Try something like ...

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml("urn:uuid:7d361fb0-bc54-48bd-bbd1-6e34960ef3f8k786
");

```
XmlElement elem = (XmlElement) doc.DocumentElement.FirstChild;
Console.Write("{0}:{1} = {2}", elem.Prefix, elem.LocalName, elem.InnerText);
Console.WriteLine("\t namespaceURI=" + elem.NamespaceURI);
```